# Preventing for loop in Python for a summation function

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, optimization

I have a vector **x** of length `10`. I want to perform the following summation in Python:

```
sum |x_{i} - x_{i-1}| over all i
```

I have written the below code, but I am sure there is a more optimal way in order to prevent the for loop. I need your suggestions.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(10,1)
sum = 0 

#note that in Python the index starts at 0
for i in range(10-1): 
    sum = sum + abs(x[i+1] - x[i])
```

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: This is almost exactly what I'd do. I'd probably generate the pairs separately using the itertools pairwise recipe, but it would end up the same. Why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: @AdamSmith because you'd generally want to use built-in vectorized operations in numpy for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can do something like:

```
np.abs(x[1:] - x[:-1]).sum()
```

Also, if you need to maintain the result as a vector, you can use:

```
np.abs(x[1:] - x[:-1]).sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this gives me different sum result that what I first did.

Comment: There is something wrong with your answer because I don't obtain the same results.

Comment: @Christina whoops! Small type, should be a negative index, see the edit

Comment: @Christina no worries, also added another small caveat